# Format JSON Object from DataTable

Tags: c#, json, t-sql, sqldataadapter

I have a SQL stored procedure that returns 2 dynamic result sets - the data(named "Table" in the JSON) and a set of columns(Table1).

Here is my C# code to run the sproc...

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TESTCONN"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Model].[TaskRecord_GetAll]", sqlcon))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", period);

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(ds);
            dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
            dt2 = ds.Tables[1];

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my current JSON object from the above code...

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "Entity": "TEST",
      "Period": "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
      "Level": "5",
      "Errors": "Approved",
      "Process": "OK",
      "Corporate": "Created"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "Entity"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Period"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Level"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Errors"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Process"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Corporate"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I need the JSON object in this format:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "Entity": "TEST",
      "Period": "2017-08-31T00:00:00",
      "Level": "5",
      "Errors": "Approved",
      "Process": "OK",
      "Corporate": "Created"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "Entity",
      "Period",
      "Level",
      "Errors",
      "Process",
      "Corporate"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my 2nd SQL result set (which feeds to Table1)...

[image]

What do I need to update in my DataTable code to ensure the desired JSON object is returned? Do I have to change the way the SQL sproc returns the data?

I cannot use LINQ/EF as the columns are dynamic and any number could be returned from the sproc.

Comment: Can you define 'ColumnName'?

Comment: "ColumnName" is the name of the column returned from the sproc. Unfortunately the values for that are dynamic so they could be anything.

Comment: If you don't want 'ColumnName' why are you returning it from procedure? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert to a list like:

```
public static class DataTableToList
{
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable dataTable)
        where T:class,new()
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        var typeOfT = typeof(T);
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var t = new T();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                var propertyName = column.ColumnName;                    
                var property = t.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    property.SetValue(t, Convert.ChangeType(row[column],property.PropertyType,null));
                }
            }
            list.Add(t);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

use:

```
    public class Table
    {
        public string Entity { get; set; }
        public int Period { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Process { get; set; }
        public string Corporate { get; set; }
    }

var list = dataTable.ToList<Table>();
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list)
```

That should do it.

Comment: Should dataTable.ToList<Table>(); read dataTable.ToList<DataTable>();

Comment: no you will have to create a class that has the properties I will update anwser

Comment: The SQL returns dynamic results so I will not know the columns before it is run. Therefore the Table class will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. I used NewtonSoft JSON to combine two JSON objects...

```
using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TESTCONN"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Model].[TaskRecord_GetAll]", sqlcon))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", period);

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(ds);
            dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
            dt2 = ds.Tables[1];

            List<DataRow> list = dt2.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            List<string> colList = new List<string>();
            foreach(DataRow row in list)
            {
                colList.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
            }

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                columns = colList
            }, Formatting.Indented);

            ds.Tables.Remove(dt2);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);

            JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(json);

            o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
            {
                // union array values together to avoid duplicates
                MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
            });
            string jsonResult = o1.ToString();

            return jsonResult;
        }
    }
}
```